# my documents are not being uploaded to firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

so i'm creating a todo list app, and it was working fine and all until i upgraded all the packages in my pubspec.yaml, which led to some nasty errors i found a way to fix it but that was when i started experiencing a problem, when i write tasks to my firestore database it doesn't add, and my stream builder doesn't see it but if i add the task manually, my stream builder still wont see it, i need help

how i solved my error in my pubspec

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 3.1.6
  firebase_crashlytics_platform_interface: 3.1.13
  cloud_firestore_platform_interface: 5.4.13
  firebase_auth_platform_interface: 6.1.11
  firebase_storage_platform_interface: 4.0.14
  cloud_functions_platform_interface: 5.0.21
  firebase_analytics_platform_interface: 3.0.5
  firebase_remote_config_platform_interface: 1.0.5
  firebase_dynamic_links_platform_interface: 0.2.0+5
  firebase_performance_platform_interface: 0.1.0+5
  firebase_app_installations_platform_interface: 0.1.0+6
```

how i add tasks to firebase

```
                        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tasks').add(
                          {
                            'name': textcontrol,
                            'description': descriptionControl,
                            'completed': false,
                            'DOC': newDate,
                            'created': DateTime.now(),
                            'time': newTime.format(context).toString(),
                          },
                        );
```

my stream builder

```
                StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData)
                      return Container(
                        height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.7,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text('press the + icon to add a task'),
                        ),
                      );
                    return Expanded(child: _buildList(snapshot.data));
                  },
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('tasks')
                      .where('completed', isEqualTo: false)
                      .snapshots(),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

When you upload something on the firebase database you have to create a doc within the collection with a unique id and then **set** your Map, so your code must look like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tasks').doc(doc_name_you_want).set(
                      {
                        'name': textcontrol,
                        'description': descriptionControl,
                        'completed': false,
                        'DOC': newDate,
                        'created': DateTime.now(),
                        'time': newTime.format(context).toString(),
                      },
                    );
```